# Network/Graph Visualization read edgelist

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import, visualization

I have what it seems to be a very trivial question, but after searching for hours I was not able to find an answer, so I am asking here.

I have an edgelist for a graph, a 2 column csv file with id1,id2 format. I simply want to import it to mathematica and display  the graph.

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
data = Import["net.csv"]

A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it:
{{1, 11724}, {1, 11725}, {1, 11726}, {1, 11727}, {1, 11728}, {1, 
11729}, {2, 107}, {2, 4050}, {2, 4050}, {2, 4054}, {2, 12202},...

Graph[data]
```

I get the error massage **Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported.** I really appreciate it if you can guide me here.

I uploaded the csv file here: [net.csv](http://www.filedropper.com/net).

Comment: it will be a great idea to upload your csv file somewhere and place a link here. Probably it's a typing mistake but Graph is the correct command.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I uploaded the file, added the link to question.

Comment: It is working fine for me!
Are you sure you are opening the right file?
Try 'Clear["Global`*"]' at the beginning of your code.

Comment: It didn't change however, PlotGraph worked for me. Could it be a version problem due to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485405/multigraphs-in-mathematica-8) I am using mathematica 9 though.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not say for sure, I use Mathematica 10.2.
Have you tried deleting the duplicates?
'DeleteDuplicates[data]'
What do you work on?
it seems interesting.

Comment: Just installed 10.2 and it works fine! thanks for the help.

Comment: @Yasmin The error message means that you have multiple edges between the same nodes. This is not supported in v9.  While v10 will be happy with multi-edges, make sure that this is what you want!  Also decide if you want a directed or undirected graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the data to the edge format can do the work

```
data = Import["net.csv"]
edges = Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]&, data]
Graph[edges]
```

Which will yield the following result

[image]

Comment: It's not necessary to convert the list elements to rules.  The reason why it worked for you and didn't work for her is that in version 9 and earlier multiple edges between the same nodes are not supported. Presumably she was using v9 and you are using v10.x.  Rules or sublists doesn't make a difference, except that rules automatically create a directed graph.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the clarity. I only have Mathematica version 10. :)